# Add space over and under footer

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

I have googled and tried every code I have found and it hasnt work. The only thing that separated the footer from the content is the `<div id="spacer">`
I need space between my content and footer. Im working with a wordpress localhost so cant give a fiddle link. But this is a picture how it looks now:
http://tinypic.com/r/rcsi10/8

I need it to look like this:

http://tinypic.com/r/hriwic/8

CSS

```
#page {
  background: white;
  width: 1020px;
  margin: 10px auto;
-moz-border-radius:15px;
-webkit-border-radius:15px;
border-radius:15px;
}
.site-footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  color: #000;
text-align: center;
background: #fff;
padding: 10px;



font-size: 11px;
margin-top: 15px;
}

#spacer {
height: 20px;
width: 1020px;
margin-top: 15px;
```

}

HTML

```
<div id="main" class="site-main">
<div id="spacer">
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
</div>
```

Comment: Would it not be possible to create an orange footer and then put the text in a textbox with a white background. Should get the same affect?

Comment: This is helpful? http://jsfiddle.net/0gjkj0uL/

Comment: If the background were just orange that could be a way, but the background has a print (lighter orange bird print) so it wouldnt look good

Comment: Should #page not be #main in your CSS, or what CSS are you applying to #main?

Comment: @Linial no, but the spacing under the footer worked, but not over it

Comment: @ConorLuddy The #page should be in the css, sorry, but the .site-main have: .site-main {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
margin: 10px;

Comment: If you put your complete CSS and HTML in the original question I'll fix it for you cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add these two css property in .site-footer, try changing top size in pixel to desired gap

```
.site-footer{
position:relative;
top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: That did work! But removed the minus. But the space under the footer isnt there

Comment: show the screen shoot, yeah try chaning top from +size to -size.

Comment: try margin-bottom css property to show space under the footer

Comment: When its -size on top, I have space under the footer, but not over the footer. When I have +size on top I have space on the top but no space under the footer

Comment: remain -size and add margin-bottom:10px; ..see what happened

Comment: .site-footer {
  clear: both;
text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;
    
    background-color:white;
position:relative;
top: -20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-size: 11px;

} http://tinypic.com/r/dvkqiu/8

Comment: try padding-bottom instead margin-bottom

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have 2 div wrap like Div 1 is the top white area and the  is the bottom footer. some thing like this.

```
//just an imaginary div 
<div class="contentarea">
 ...............
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>   

<div id="spacer" style="margin-top:10px;">
   <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo"></footer>
</div>
```

normal case this is enough to make a space between the two div content area and the spacer. make sure you don't give bg color for the wrapper.